# How to remove some special character from word using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am splitting file in words. I am able to splitting it into word but in some  word there is special character like '___'. I want to skip that special character nd also split that word from that special character.

The file which contains data like this

```
Yahoo$$$Yahoo OK : ___GET
Gmail$$$Gmail Ok:___GET
google_data$$$Google.com.in___POST
```

using ((?!:)[.0-9a-zA-Z\s]\w+)+  gives me

```
Yahoo
Yahoo OK
 ___GET
Gmail
Gmail Ok
GET
google_data
Google.com.in___POST
```

I don't want that '___' and also the following string:

```
Google.com.in___POST
```

has to be split in two words, like:

```
Google.com.in
POST
```

Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\w` will also match an underscore. Looking at the example data, you want to match characters a-z or a digit, and in between there can be a space, dot or underscore.

Instead of splitting, you might match the values:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:[._ ][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` Match a digit or a-z in lower or uppercase 1+ times
- `(?:` Non caputuring group

  - `[._ ]` Match a . _ or space
  - `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` Match a digit or a-z in lower or uppercase 1+ times
- `)*` Close on capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QhiaQN/1)

Comment: @User1111 You are welcome. I have updated the regex.

Comment: Thanks. This is also fine.